# How can I label a matrix's opening delimiter with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, delimiters, tikz-arrows

I have few hours experience with `tikz`. I am trying to highlight the matrix delimiters with arrows, but just can't figure out how to accurately position, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
  {
    8 &8 &1 &6 \\
    3 &8 &5 &7 \\
    4 &8 &9 &5 \\
  };

  \draw[color=red,double,implies-](m-1-1.north) -- +(0,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives [image]

The arrow is pointing on the (1,1)th element of the matrix, how do I position it right above the left delimiter `(`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place it relative to `m.north west` instead, i.e.

```
\draw[color=red,double,implies-]([xshift=-4pt]m.north west) -- +(0,0.3);
```

As you can see some manual adjustment (the `xshift`) is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
  {
    8 &8 &1 &6 \\
    3 &8 &5 &7 \\
    4 &8 &9 &5 \\
  };

  \draw[color=red,double,implies-]([xshift=-4pt]m.north west) -- +(0,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! i actually tried to play with xshift, just didn't get the right position;-)